# What happens when a victim of child sexual abuse comes forward to a priest?

Tags: catholicism

What happens when a victim of child sex abuse comes forward to a priest? Is the victim encouraged to report the crime to authorities?

Since this may occur outside the confessional would a priest be free to report the crime to authorities?
Or are there confidentiality protocols in the church that prohibit a priest who learns of CSA through counseling session from reporting the crime?

Comment: The seal of confession would only apply to *perpetrator*, not the *victim*.

Comment: @Null. Still are there confidentiality protocols in the church that prohibit a priest who learns of Csa through counseling session from reporting the crime?

Comment: Are you assuming that the accused person is a priest? Or just a member of the public?

Comment: @DJClayworth not a priest   The perp could be anyone for the sake of this question

Comment: As far as I know, the seal of confession applies to all information that a priest knows (only) from someone's  confession --- whether the "someone" is the perpetrator, victim, bystander,  or just some random person. It even applies to incidental information separate from any sin confessed; if I mention in confession that some company is about to go bankrupt, the priest can't use that information to sell his stock in that company.

Answer (score 2):

**What happens when a victim of *child sexual abuse* comes forward to a priest?**

Nowadays, after notifying the local ordinary (bishop), that some sexual allegations have been made, the local police are to be immediately notified.

> In 2007, the Canadian Conference of Catholic Bishops issued a series of protocols for the dioceses to follow, which among other things advised bringing in police immediately to deal with abuse accusations, rather than handling them internally at first. - [Catholic Church sexual abuse cases in Canada](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catholic_Church_sexual_abuse_cases_in_Canada#:%7E:text=In%202007%2C%20the%20Canadian%20Conference,handling%20them%20internally%20at%20first.)

Many other countries and dioceses have similar policies in place nowadays.